# when i press save button is showing me _cast error, I am creating shop app from academine course

Tags: android, flutter, dart

when i press save button in the app i stuck and showing me in line 46 .productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String;
this is the error.
the Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast) in this code . final
.
when i add ? sign in the as String (as String?) then the app didnt show the product in the other
screen.

[image]

/
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/products.dart';

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/edit-product';

  const EditProductScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _EditProductScreenState createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _editedProduct = Product(
    id: '',
    title: '',
    price: 0,
    description: '',
    imageUrl: '',
  );
  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
  };
  var _isInit = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String;
      if (productId != null) {
        _editedProduct =
            Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).findById(productId);
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedProduct.title,
          'description': _editedProduct.description,
          'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
          // 'imageUrl': _editedProduct.imageUrl,
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
      }else{
        print("something went wrong");
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlController.dispose();
    _imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (!_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      if ((!_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('http') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('https')) ||
          (!_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.png') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpg') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpeg'))) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id!, _editedProduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProduct(_editedProduct);
    }
    print(_editedProduct.title);
    print(_editedProduct.id);
    print(_editedProduct.description);
    print(_editedProduct.imageUrl);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Product'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: _saveForm,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _form,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please provide a value.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                      title: value!,
                      price: _editedProduct.price,
                      description: _editedProduct.description,
                      imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                      id: _editedProduct.id,
                      isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite);
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price'),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionFocusNode);
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a price.';
                  }
                  if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                    return 'Please enter a valid number.';
                  }
                  if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                    return 'Please enter a number greater than zero.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                      title: _editedProduct.title,
                 price: double.parse(value!),
                      description: _editedProduct.description,
                      imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                      id: _editedProduct.id,
                      isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite);
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
                maxLines: 3,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a description.';
                  }
                  if (value.length < 10) {
                    return 'Should be at least 10 characters long.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                    title: _editedProduct.title,
                    price: _editedProduct.price,
                    description: value!,
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                    id: _editedProduct.id,
                    isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                  );
                },
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8,
                      right: 10,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                        ? Text('Enter a URL')
                        : FittedBox(
                            child: Image.network(
                              _imageUrlController.text,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      controller: _imageUrlController,
                      focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        _saveForm();
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter an image URL.';
                        }
                        if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                            !value.startsWith('https')) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid URL.';
                        }
                        if (!value.endsWith('.png') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid image URL.';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                          price: _editedProduct.price,
                          description: _editedProduct.description,
                          imageUrl: value!,
                          id: _editedProduct.id,
                          isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because  `ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments` is a `Null`. Make sure you are having value before you cast it as `String.`

To get away with the error you can cast only when it is not `Null`.

```
 final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments != Null ? 
                   ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String :
                   'Invalid_productId' ;
```

Comment: sir it still giving me the same error .Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

Comment: i uploaded this code in Github can you help to solve this small issue?

Comment: You just have to make sure you fill the value of `ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments` and that is not null before casting it as string, that should solve your issue.

Comment: sir i am learning. that is where i stuck . i have github repo so you could clone it and just solve it . i would take 5 min.

Comment: sir this is my github repo .https://github.com/Shazad222/stackoverflow

Comment: in screen /edit_product_screen.dart line 46 has some error

Answer (score 0):

i used  id: '', in the var

```
_editedProduct = Product(
    id: '',
    title: '',
    price: 0,
    description: '',
    imageUrl: '',
  );
```

and in the if statement i compare it _editedProduct.id with null

```
if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id!, _editedProduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProduct(_editedProduct);
    }
```

so when i change   if (_editedProduct.id != null)  to   if (_editedProduct.id != '') then the code run successfully
i also change the

```
final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String
```

to this

```
final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?
```

just put ? sign with the String